# XML Query with multiple attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<LoSTResponseBodyType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <LoSTResponseAdapter xmlns="urn:adapt:xml:ns:DataTypes:2.0">
       <findServiceResponse xmlns="urn:lost:params:xml:ns:lost1">
           <mapping sourceId="9999" expires="2015-08-24T14:27:58Z" lastUpdated="2015-06-17T21:36:43Z" source="mysourcename">
              <displayName xml:lang="en">mydisplayname</displayName>
              <service>myservice</service>
              <uri>myuri</uri>
              <serviceNumber>mynumber</serviceNumber>
           </mapping>
      </findServiceResponse>
    </LoSTResponseAdapter>
</LoSTResponseBodyType>
```

How do I retrieve the value for `<uri>`, ie `myuri`?

I have tried the following code

```
WITH xmlnamespaces ('urn:adapt:xml:ns:DataTypes:2.0' as datatype,
                    'urn:lost:params:xml:ns:lost1' as findtype)
SELECT EventBody.value('(/LoSTResponseBodyType/datatype:LoSTResponseAdapter/findtype:findServiceResponse/mapping/uri)[1]', 'varchar(max)') 
FROM mytable
```

I do get a value of NULL.

If i remove everything 'mapping/uri', i do get all values all concatenated together, ie displayname, service, uri, serviceNumber and it would look like this:
mydisplaynamemyservicemyurimynumber

Comment: Have you tried adding the `findtype` prefix to `mapping` and `uri` in your path? Those are also in the same namespace as `findServiceResponse`

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, that's what was missing indeed ! Appreciate it

Comment: @xQueryUser: You should invite Daniel Haley to submit his comment as an answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: This isn't exactly standard XQuery. Is it Microsoft's SQL-integrated bastardization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `findtype` prefix to `mapping` and `uri` in your xpath.

Those elements are also in the same namespace as `findServiceResponse`.